# I need to Create a linear or one-dimensional array/list A of size n containing integer values, where n is a valid integer. n could be 20

Tags: python

Who can Create a linear or one-dimensional array/list A of size n containing integer values, where n is a valid integer. n could be 20?

Comment: Does it need manual input or some random values?

Comment: How about `list(range(n))`?

Answer (score 2):

Simple but works.

```py
n = 20
list(range(n))
```

Comment: May be use **list(range(1,n+1))** to strat from **1** to **20**

Comment: @AziMez nice idea yes, I just considered 0 to be a valid integer for the question